# How can I add Ubuntu to a windows domain with LikewiseOpen?

Tags: 14.04

I want to join with my Ubuntu 14.04 Computer to a windows domain (2012 R2).

I tried install [likewise-open](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen) but it didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen), likewise-open is not supported anymore, and it's not in the repositories. You probably tried to follow an old tutorial like me and failed because of that.

They recomend the use of [Beyond Trust](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Resources/OpenSourceDocumentation/?Pass=True), open edition, but I've never tried myself, so maybe someone can add a better solution.